# SQL Server syntax for Last of a Text. I want 1 record per license number so Top doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT A.link_key, A.licn_no, B.licn_state
FROM dbo.liclink A 
INNER JOIN dbo.license B 
ON A.licn_key = B.licn_key
WHERE (B.licn_state = 'MA')
GROUP BY A.link_key, A.licn_no, B.licn_state
ORDER BY A.link_key, A.licn_no DESC;
```

--I want the last license number because there are duplicate license numbers in there so TOP doesn't work.  I tried TOP (1) but it returned 1 record only.  License number is a short text data type field so please keep that in mind.

Comment: would removing licn_no from the group by list, and selecting max(A.licn_no) be what you're looking for?

Comment: You're joining tables, so perhaps it is best to divide the problem into pieces and focus on finding "last license" from the license table first. Once that is working, then add your join.

Answer (score 3):

I think `cross apply` is the easiest method (and probably the best performing):

```
SELECT A.link_key, A.licn_no, B.licn_state
FROM dbo.liclink A CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 B.*
      FROM dbo.license B 
      WHERE  A.licn_key = B.licn_key AND B.licn_state = 'MA'
      ORDER BY ?? DESC
     ) B
ORDER BY A.link_key, A.licn_no DESC;
```

I'm not sure what column determines the latest.  That is what the `??` represents.

A rather inscrutable but fun method doesn't use subqueries at all:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES A.link_key, A.licn_no, B.licn_state
FROM dbo.liclink A INNER JOIN
     dbo.license B 
     ON A.licn_key = B.licn_key
WHERE (B.licn_state = 'MA')
GROUP BY A.link_key, A.licn_no, B.licn_state
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.link_key ORDER BY A.licn_no DESC),
         A.link_key, A.licn_no DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Unfortunately that didn't return accurate results. I have a standard query to compare it to and the record count didn't come close to it.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: @AmyC . . . This does what your question asks.  I don't know what your "standard query" does.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the top method returns 1 result and I need it to take the last licn_no per link_key.

Comment: @AmyC . . . The `TOP` method should return one row per `link_key`/`licn_no` pair.

Comment: Hi Gordon, it did not.  I'm using MS Access Sql Server - in a pass-through query.